# Conditional formatting to highlight cells between two dates

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

so this is what I have so far: In Excel I am looking to highlight a range of cells which is going to be indicated by the start date column and end date column.

My formula can determine when the start date is true, but for some reason my 2nd parameter is always true, thus leading the format to reach all the way to the end.

Formula:
=AND(J$1>=$H8, J$1<=$I8)

Screenshot:
[image]

How could the 2nd parameter always be true? I have formatted both H and I columns to be Date format. Thanks.

Comment: There is something wrong with your data. See [this quick mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9mib.png).

Comment: Any idea @Jeeped ? I have set both columns to Date format... Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: If you want to post a redacted copy to a public file share and [edit] your question (not as a comment) to include the link then I will have a look but it is impossible to determine without seeing the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sub>I have formatted both H and I columns to be Date format.</sub>

Not correctly.

If you look closely at the (largely) unformatted dates in I8:I11 you may note that the displayed values are left-aligned. By default, dates and numbers are right-aligned in a cell; text is left-aligned. The left-alignment tells me those are v and not true dates. It is possible that you have trailing spaces, non-breaking spaces or some other rogue character.

If I manually force the true dates in my sample to be text-that-look-like-dates, I get the same results you are experiencing.

Select I8:I11 and and set to General cell format then run Data, Text-to-Columns, Fixed width, Date: mdy, Finish.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This works. Although this will set the ranges for my dates, it will not allow me to dynamically set the color of the cells based on column F... so I ended up writing my own VBA code to do this all for me. Still, I appreciate your help and getting to the bottom of this. Just curious... is there a way to use Conditional Formatting to also set the cell colors to be the same as the cell in the same row under column F?